# Who owns NASDAQ? Does it collect fees from stock transactions?

Tags: stocks, fees, stock-exchanges

If NASDAQ is a corporation, does it make profits by charging fees on transactions? When I pay a fee for buying stocks, am I paying the broker or NASDAQ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[NASDAQ OMX Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ_OMX_Group) owns NASDAQ, a [stock exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_exchange).

It is a corporation, and is listed on the NASDAQ as [NDAQ](http://www.google.com/finance?q=ndaq).

It makes money by:

> 1. They charge each company to list their stock in their market.
> 2. They charge for transaction that is taking place on their exchange server
> 3. They may be offering other financial or other listing (or IPO) related services in a package deal with contracted third parties.

[source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070627135039AA16x5I)

NASDAQ also charges for market data services, found in the [NASDAQ "Datastore"](https://data.nasdaq.com/).

Other information about the fees charged by NYSE and NASDAQ may be found in the Investopedia article [*The NYSE And Nasdaq: How They Work*](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/03/103103.asp#axzz1s99h13cd).

Comment: Just to add, the fee you pay goes to the broker. However the broker pays NASDAQ fee that are yearly as well as per transaction.

Comment: The NASDAQ per-transaction fees appear to be very low: $0.0005
to $0.0035 per share, it looks like, depending on how they actually execute the trade. If you're paying a broker ~$4-$20 a trade and *not* transacting tens of thousands of shares with each order, the Nasdaq part of that is essentially nothing. http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=PriceListTrading2

Comment: @fennec But that's not really the point; It may be "essentially nothing" to the buyer and seller, but very much significant to NASDAQ, since it occurs for *every single share* of *every NASDAQ stock*.  Because the $$ volume of total trades is enormous, it surely adds up as sizable income for NASDAQ.

Comment: @fennec According to NASDAQ they currently transact around 2 billion per day. At your lowest price/share, that would be over $1mil per day! http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=DailyMarketSummary